# Site for asking questions for resume advice in computer science field

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask some questions regarding résumé writing. I am having some confusion about some technical stuff in computer science, whether I should write it or not.

I know https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ is a good option, but where can I get advice about technical stuff? Is there a site where I can ask for résumé writing advice, but is mainly for computer science people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workplace doesn't accept such questions, according to their [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### What questions are off topic here?
>
> [Questions asking for advice on what to do](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) (including [reviewing resumes, CVs,](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596) ...

These kind of questions are too broad and/or attract opinionated answers (*project X is amaz1ng!!, you should definitely include that in your resume*) and are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model, so I doubt you can find a proper site.

Comment: Should a feature request be opened for a site in the stack exchange that does this? I could see it being useful...

Comment: If you want to propose a new site, that's what [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) is for. However, I'm not sure if a Resume Review proposal would fly.

Comment: More of a business help area. For things like interview help etc...

Comment: Also when I tried to sign up with my email I got No account with this email found

Comment: I don't know what causes that error, sorry.